# Nvidia display driver stop working frequently

Tags: linux, windows-7, driver, ubuntu-14.04

I have dual booted windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 on my PC.

I have a recurring problem with windows.

The screen frequently becomes blank for a few seconds, showing an error message in a popup menu:

> "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered. Display driver NVIDIA windows kernel mode driver version 266.58 stopped responding and has successfully recovered."

Here are my computer specifications:

> Intel core i5 processor,
>
> 4gb ram,
>
> Nvidia GeForce 210 graphics card.

I updated the drivers on my computer.

I also formatted my PC, but the problem still persists.

Now the problem is worse and windows shuts down within a few minutes of starting.

Today, Ubuntu also started randomly freezing, a symptom which had not presented itself until now.

Comment: Honestly, this particular question doesn't fit stack overflow, since it isn't strictly programming related. (As far as I can tell, you have a hardware issue.) Since it persists across two different OS, with very different arch, I would say you need a new gpu. A Nvidia GT 730 is under $50 USD and would be a suitable replacement/upgrade for your 200.

Answer (score 0):

As Astor139 said:

> Honestly, this particular question doesn't fit stack overflow, since it isn't strictly programming related. (As far as I can tell, you have a hardware issue.) Since it persists across two different OS, with very different arch, I would say you need a new gpu. A Nvidia GT 730 is under $50 USD and would be a suitable replacement/upgrade for your 200.

Posted as his comment is really a suitable answer.